# One to many + many to many in the same model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a 1 to many and a many to many realtionships between:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
    public int Distance { get; set; }

    public List<Sport> Sports { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("UserCreatorId")]
    public ICollection<Event> EventsCreated { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Users")]
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string SportName { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int NumUsersJoined { get; set; }
    [Required, Range(2,50, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 2 and 50")]
    public int MaxNumUsers { get; set; }

    public Guid UserCreatorId { get; set; }    

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

The many to many relationship it's working ok, but the 1:many isn't, it's making an extra column in database in the event table User_UserId and making it the foreign key instead of the UserCreatorId which is what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can many-to-many work? Where is the intermediary table?

Comment: how ? many-to-many is creating te correct UserEvents table with UserId and EventId keys.

Comment: Oh ok, I was not aware that this happens behind the scenes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this,

in `Event`,

```
 [ForeignKey("UserCreator")]
 public Guid UserCreatorId { get; set; }  

  public User UserCreator{ get; set; }  
 [InverseProperty("Events")]
public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

and,
in `User`

```
   [InverseProperty("UserCreator")]
    public ICollection<Event> EventsCreated { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried, now I am getting this exception: Message "If you specify the FOREIGN KEY constraint 'User_EventsCreated' on table 'Events' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. \ R \ nNo could not create constraint. See previous errors. "string

Comment: you can make `UserCreatorId` null-able or make this relationship casecadeDelete false in configuration.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm newbie, what do you mean in configuration ?

Comment: Hmm.. you can configure all there things you have done using data annotations  in the model configuration using fluent API. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Try doing this `[ForeignKey("UserCreator")]
 public Guid? UserCreatorId{ get; set; }  `

Comment: That work's! What means the "?" in the type of the property ?

Comment: That means its nullable, that means cascade delete =false